# CSS divs do not fit on all resolutions

Tags: html, css

When i make websites, it fits on my screen, but when i open the website on another screen, it doesn't work correctly (The divs overlaps eachother). It's the same when i resize the window. I saw a couple of posts about this, but still, no good answer. I tried making a container to put them all in. But it's still the same.

Any answers, why this is happening?

Container CSS code:

```
#container
{
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I put it into HTML like this:

```
<div id="container">
Content goes here
</div>
```

EDIT: Guys, i don't think you understand me. When i'm on another screen resolution, all the divs moves. I think everything moves, if i'm not completely wrong. I would like to know the real way of doing this. What do you do?

http://i49.tinypic.com/8wwo6r.jpg

http://i48.tinypic.com/359ydc9.jpg

FINAL EDIT: I fixed it with the percentage. It seems to work quite well! Thanks for all your answers! I know this will give me a kind of bad reputation, because i didn't make myself clear enough.

Comment: You specified your div to always be 960px, so if the resolution of the screen is less than 960px wide, then of course it's not all going to fit on the screen.

Comment: Soo.. i Don't have to choose a width? Sorry, i'm pretty new.

Comment: What you probably want is called a fluid layout. Fluid layouts use percentages of the screen. i.e. `width: 80%`

Comment: Doesn't work.. Still the same

Comment: You need to do some learning about CSS, the box model, and how the width property works I think

Comment: Hmm.. I used some of that, but isn't it possible to use pixels, but still fitting to all resolutions?

Comment: Not without detecting the user's resolution and swapping out the stylesheets based on that, which isn't a pure CSS solution.

Comment: I'm pretty new to all of this, but i do have some CSS skills. What is the box model? I understand the width method i think.

Comment: The [IronMeyers Layouts site](http://layouts.ironmyers.com/) may help you get started quickly (pick a fluid layout).

Comment: Can you tell me how the regular method of making this, works?

Comment: Box Model: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Comment: Jeroen, i want to build websites from scratch. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, and Crush, but why is this failing for me? Is it lack of css skills? Or is this common?

Comment: Are you sure your CSS is even taken into account? Add a `background-color: #FF0000;` to it or so. Do you have your CSS defined inside the `<style></style>` tags within the `<head></head>` ?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" /> ?? :)

Comment: "Guys, i don't think you understand me." You're right about that.

Comment: Sorry, but this is hard to explain.

Comment: @user2007556: no, it's not. You need to tell us: 1. What you've tried (i.e. what code have you written, and what are you doing to view that code); 2. What you expect to see; and 3. What you're actually seeing. You've been quite vague about 2, 3, and the second half of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use percentages instead of pixel.

```
#container {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

---

You can figure out percentages having screen resolution and the size you want using this forumla:

`WidthPercentage = ContainerWidth / ScreenWidth * 100`

So for your example if your screen resolution is 1360x768:

`WidthPercentage = 960 / 1360 * 100 = 70.5%`

---

This is called [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

You can find some guidelines [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design) and some good articles [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/).

Comment: Thanks :) But this makes it a little harder to choose a precise width and height.. :S

Comment: @user2007556: You figure it out with some math. Let's assume your screen resolution is `1024x768`. If you want a 800px width container percentage you have to divide the container width (800) by the total width (1024) and multiply by 100. 78.125% will be the answer.

Comment: Argh. Math. My weaknes... Thanks for the example! ;)

Comment: @user2007556 just added to the answer.

Comment: Do i have to make the height, percentages too? Or just the width?

Comment: @user2007556: Well, only if you need. Users can scroll easily vertically, so you have to use height only in pages where you don't want any scrollbar.

Comment: Okay thank you. It's the height and width, i have to change, right? Not the "margin-left: 10%;" and those position things, right? Or is it both? :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use percentages, you can go with **Responsive Design** and **Media Queries**. Basically, you call different CSS rules based on different browser properties (for example: width). See a nice tutorial about this [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design) (you can also see it in action).

Quote:

> The second part of responsive design is CSS3 media queries, which currently enjoy decent support across many modern browsers. If you’re not familiar with CSS3 media queries, they basically allow you to gather data about the site visitor and use it to conditionally apply CSS styles. For our purposes, we’re primarily interested in the min-width media feature, which allows us to apply specific CSS styles if the browser window drops below a particular width that we can specify

Comment: I just did. :) Can you provide a link to see that?

Comment: Then I can't help you much, except to say that the actual site header is never put inside the `head` part of the page. All presentational elements go inside `body`. If you want to show us the page, you can use jsfiddle.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Can i upload the folder with the content to you? Would that help?

Comment: It would, but I think it might be easier to try and reconstruct it in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Okay hold on a second. I will copy it to Jsfiddle.

Comment: Okay, that just mess it all up. And the pictures is on my local drive, so that isn't showed..

Comment: Ok, I could manage without the original pictures if you set sizes for them. So, what's the main problem?

Comment: First off, remove all the divs and each presentational content from the `head`, like I said.

Comment: All the divs moves on a different screen resolution, as i told in the edit. It's really hard to explain. Let me take a screenshot, and edit it into the question. 2 seconds

Comment: Thanks :) I posted the pictures.

Comment: Ok, so you don't want the small left div to overlap with the main one?

Comment: No, i want it as it is on the first link ;) But the left div isn't all the side to the left. It is in the middle. But edited a little bit, so it moved a little. But nearly the same as it should be. :)

Comment: `.divdate` has a left margin of 8px, which is what moves it. Set it to 0px and it will be all the way to the left. http://jsfiddle.net/PAHDf/2/

Comment: Hmm.. Didn't really change anything, but i can change that myself  ;) Don't you have a solution for the real problem? :)

Comment: You still haven't said what's the real problem.

Comment: The problem is that the div comes closer to the maindiv. That's why i need help. Everytime i make a new div, it doesn't show up correctly on the Largest screen. It's the same as the header and background. I made a different header, so the maindiv scrolls up underneath it, if you know what i mean. You can see the sword is moved on the header image. If you look on the biggest screen picture.

Comment: But it's sticked to the left margin, it has to come closer. You could potentially stick the maindiv to the right margin, but they'll still come together at some point... This is where you need to use the responsive design I told you - find at what width they touch each other, and then do something (reduce the maindiv, hide the datediv, etc.)

Comment: Okay i think this is becoming too advanced for me. Still.. I will not give up :). Thanks for all your answers and you patience. This really helped me. You did see the edit i wrote in the last comment, right?

Comment: I see you edited the comment. Well, the sword solution is that you need to use a single image (on the body or container) and set it to center top and that's it. The real problem you'll encounter is when the datediv and maindiv overlap. This looks fine: http://jsfiddle.net/PAHDf/3/

Comment: Hmm.. I'm really getting confused here.. I think i would need some voice support or something. Thanks.

Comment: You need to slowly learn your way of coding HTML/CSS until you reach advanced levels of responsive layouts, floating divs, static divs... So the whole time the issue **was** overlapping, which I originally addressed in my answer, yet we continued working on some minor things. Can't help you more than that, sorry.

Comment: No problem. It was all my problem. I misunderstood you. ;) Thanks for all your patience!

Answer (score 0):

You've set your `<div>` (`<div id="container">`) to be 960 pixels wide. If you view the page in a browser window that's less than 960 pixels wide, then the `<div>` won't fit in it.

Your question isn't very clear. You've said "when i open the website on another screen, it doesn't work correctly", but you haven't said *how* it doesn't work. To get help, you need to describe the following three things with enough detail:

- What you've done (e.g. what code you've written, what steps you're taking to run that code)
- What results you expect from what you've done
- What results you're actually getting

Comment: Okay. When you resize webpages like facebook, they don't start to overlap eachother. That is what it does on my webpage. I want it to be like facebook. The divs gets smaller but don't start overlapping eachother. On this link, the window is resized. http://i47.tinypic.com/x4nb6r.jpg

Comment: Haha, I asked you about half an hour ago whether the overlapping was the problem and you said no, the left div isn't on the screen edge... and after that you said the background (sword) moves on resize... I give up.

Comment: The overlapping is the problem. The problem is everything i have done on my 1400x900 screen (Background, header, divs etc.), is moving on a different screen. I want it to look exactly the same.. Aaargh... I don't know what to do. What to explain..

Comment: Okay.. I think i need to use percentages. I think that's the answer. I'll try that. If you got any help, just type :)

Comment: Thanks guys! That's it! Aaaw i could kiss you all!

Comment: @user2007556: "When you resize webpages like facebook, they don't start to overlap eachother." You mean *the different layout columns* don't start to overlap each other.